# What equality is used by Hash methods?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have class `Foo`, and I overload two of its methods `==` and `eql?`:

```
class Foo

  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end

  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def ==(o)
    self.bar == o.bar
  end

  def .eql?(o)
    return ==(o)
  end

end
```

I test that `f1` and `f2` below are equal with respect to the two methods:

```
u = User.find(12345)
f1 = Foo.new(u)
f2 = Foo.new(u)

f1 == f2    # => true
f1.eql?(f2) # => true
```

But `Hash#has_key?` does not render them equal:

```
{f1 => true}.has_key?(f2) # => false
```

What is the equality method used in `Hash#has_key?`?

Comment: Your first code block has some errors, probably introduced when you cut it down for the example. Or, more accurately, I cannot replicate your results using `Foo` as written

Comment: You're right @neil-slater , I removed the initialize method and accessors for more visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most implementations of a hash type, Ruby’s included, rely on a hash first (for speed!) and then equality checks. To verify that it works, first, you can just add

```
def hash
    1
end
```

After that, you should work on providing as many possible distinct return values for `hash` that will still be equal if the objects are considered equal (as long as it’s fast, of course).

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly. I used the object hash passed into arguments of initialize, like this : https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/181819

Answer (score 2):

It uses `hash` method. You may concatinate properties of your objects there or something like that. In your case you want hash value to be the same for 2 objects if and only if they are equal.

Comment: It uses `hash` *and* `eql?`. It *needs* to check `eql?` as well for identical `hash` values because of the Pigeonhole Principle.