# I'm having difficulty understanding a concept in Hash Tables

Tags: hash, language-agnostic, hashmap, hashtable

I understand the allure of hash tables is that you get O(1) lookup times, but I'm having difficulty understanding how the storage component works.

I understand Hash Tables use a key-value pair, where given a certain key you can get its particular value back. So if I wanted to associate a name with a phone number, I could have "Paul" as the key, and the phone number as the value I then receive. I understand that much.

- So does it work in that at the array index that "Paul" get hashed to (say, `3`), the value there will be a phone number, thus the O(1) lookup time?
- I know collisions are the bane of hash tables, and it seems the most popular way is to put a linked list at each entry instead of a raw value, but how does that then work when looking values up? If there's only one value I can essentially say "get me the value at that index" but if there's multiple phone numbers stored at "Paul"'s hashed index, how do I know which one is actually Paul's?

Answer (score 1):

> if there's multiple phone numbers stored at "Paul"'s hashed index, how do I know which one is actually Paul's?

Generally, each entry would be checked for equality individually after that, in the same way as a regular search across a linked list.

> So does it work in that at the array index that "Paul" get hashed to (say, 3), the value there will be a phone number, thus the O(1) lookup time?

Pretty much! The hashed value is usually first converted to a bucket number somehow, since hash results can exceed a reasonable size for a lookup table (e.g. four billion).

Comment: What do you mean by "would be checked for equality"? How would that occur?

Comment: @Aloha64: However you (and the language) decide. In the case of your phone number, probably a string comparison. [Python gets the hash with `__hash__` and checks equality with `__eq__`.](http://codepad.org/lL46mzqJ) .NET uses `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. [Ruby uses `.eql?` and `.hash`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758968/what-equality-is-used-by-hash-methods/21759184#21759184)

Answer (score 0):

> if there's multiple phone numbers stored at "Paul"'s hashed index, how
>   do I know which one is actually Paul's?

The items stored in a hash table bucket include more than the phone number (the value). The hash table stores *both* the key *and* the value.

> So does it work in that at the array index that "Paul" get hashed to
>   (say, 3), the value there will be a phone number, thus the O(1) lookup
>   time?

Yes, when "Paul" gets hashed to "3", usually the item at hash_table[3] stores *both* the name "Paul" *and* Paul's phone number -- usually there is no collision.
But occasionally there is a collision,
and the first item at hash_table[3] stores some other name.
The main difference between different hash table algorithms is how they handle collisions (their ["collision resolution strategy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)), where the `lookup("Paul")` function looks next for Paul's name and phone number.